# setting Sleep time for a while loop in php

Tags: php, mysql

hey guys I'm trying to write an update script in which i need to set sleep time for each row and then continue the process

as long as the process is so giant and cannot be done at once ( switching Latin-1 Charset into UTF-8 ) then i need sleep time after each row is converted

this is a usual and working code to convert into utf-8 but the sleep time doesn't work and again its doing it all at once .

```
 ob_implicit_flush();

 $result = $db->sql_query("SHOW TABLES");
 while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
  $db->sql_query("ALTER TABLE $row[0] COLLATE $collation");
  $result1 = $db->sql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $row[0]");
  while ($row1 = $db->sql_fetchrow($result1)) {
   if (preg_match('~char|text|enum|set~', $row1["Type"])) {
    $db->sql_query("ALTER TABLE $row[0] MODIFY $row1[Field] $row1[Type] CHARACTER SET binary");
    $db->sql_query("ALTER TABLE $row[0] MODIFY $row1[Field] $row1[Type] COLLATE $collation" . ($row1["Null"] ? "" : " NOT NULL") . ($row1["Default"] && $row1["Default"] != "NULL" ? " DEFAULT '$row1[Default]'" : ""));
   }
   echo"sleep for 2 seconds ....<br> $row[0] is already converted.";  
 // wait for 2 seconds 
   usleep(2000000);
   // back!
   echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";

  }

 }
```

Comment: The process may be "giant" but you can "stack" MySQL queries via PHP anyway. The process won't take any longer with than without stack (or time between queries...). All you're doing is possibly making it even longer. PHP engine != MySQL engine

Comment: thanks but do u mind to write an example script as an answer ?!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simple sleep command

sleep(2);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are 'sleeping' between every table not between every column update - is that the way you wanted it to be? Anyway if data is big 2 seconds may be too low time

There was also a bug in Windows PHP where you had to set infinite time limit or sleep would make high CPU usage.

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Simon, I can see that there is some merit in leaving gaps between the updates, however Why do you update each column in a seperate operation? It'll be a lot faster if you change them all at once.

Answer (score -1):

I do not see the effort of your sleep. What are you waiting for during those two seconds? The script can not do an other job while its sleeping.